# Is it possible to update a field in a record which is the same field used in the where clause

Tags: sql

I know the question doesn't sound realistic and here's a piece of code of what I'm trying to do.

```
UPDATE    Players
SET PlayerID = 100, Name = 'L. Messi', PlayerWebsite = 'www.messi.com'
WHERE     (PlayerID = 43)
```

see, I'm trying to update a value, which I'm already using in my where clause
I know it doesn't even make sense! but if I wanted to do so, is there a possible way or kind of a trick to do it ? and if this is possible, do you think it's bad practice or it's gonna cause problems ?

Thanks in advance =)

**EDIT**
I'm sorry if I wasn't clear before, But this query doesn't run

Comment: It could cause problems if other tables rely on PlayerId, otherwise no.

Comment: It does rely on other tables and other tables rely on it, but can't I just specify what to do "ON UPDATE"

Comment: "Cannot update identity column 'PlayerID'"

Comment: If its a primary key - then you should never be changing it, thats part of what being a primary key is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a trick to do it.  It is allowed and your code should work.

If the ID column is a key though, you would not be able to if the ID already exists.

To see if the column is a key, try running the following:

```
SELECT K.TABLE_NAME,
K.COLUMN_NAME,
K.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS C
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS K
ON C.TABLE_NAME = K.TABLE_NAME
AND C.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = K.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
AND C.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = K.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
AND C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = K.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
AND K.COLUMN_NAME = 'PlayerID';
```

If a row is returned, it is a primary key and you need to check if the ID you are changing to exists before updating a record.

**Edit:**
Since it is an `IDENTITY` column, you need to use some tricks to get around it:
http://blogs.3sharp.com/deving/archive/2005/11/04/971.aspx

Or you could not make it an `IDENTITY`.

Comment: the id doesn't exist but the column ID is incremented automatically, would that be the problem ? -because my query doesn't run-

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the exact way. This method is used all the time, for example, for optimistic concurrency. The where clause verifies each field has the expected value before updating the record. If someone else edited the record between your first retrieving it and your saving of changes, no records would be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is possible, but changing primary key (`PlayerID` is your PK, I bet) is a weird practice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it IS possible, but it's definitely bad practice to do it specifically on the **ID** field, unless you're doing a one-time migration thing.

Comment: it's not a one-time thing, although it would be rarely used but it's just an advanced option I thought I'd like to add...and btw it's connected with other tables but can I just specify what to do "ON UPDATE" ?